# Apply texture to specific "square" (two triangles) of Mesh Plane unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, uv-mapping

I am looking for a way to apply a texture to a specific square of a mesh when that square is clicked on. I know how to get the vertices of the square from a Physics.raycast & converting the triangle vertices. My problem is I don't know how to apply the texture.

Here is an example of what I want to do. Before Click:

[image: Before Click]

And then if I clicked on the upper left square. After Click:

[image: After Click]

(except the colors would be textures).

Any help is greatly appreciated! Ty!

Comment: You can either use specialized Shader (which is IMHO overkill) or just simply render a decal (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/496000/how-do-you-make-decals-render-over-other-objects.html).
Anyway here on SO you should ask using [MCVE], this *discussion-like* questions should be asked on other sites like https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note: decals are handled as entirely separate meshes. Also, such questions are *not* appropriate for Game Dev, it's a Q&A site like the majority of the SE network. Always check the "how to ask" page before posting.

Comment: @Draco18s I may be wrong, but I believe that this kind of question would be more appropriate to be on Game Dev. Not in it's current form, obviously, but I think that Q like "I wanto to do this and that, which approach is more suitable for me: A or B or C?" should be there instead of here (because here it probably would get deleted as *too broad* or *opinion based*). Am I correct?

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich Game Dev would *also* close it as being *too broad* or *opinion based.* While Game Dev does allow for questions dealing with code (they used to be mercilessly migrated to SO), the *basis* for a good question is "do I need a game designer (or game programmer) to answer this question?" And this question does not need that.

Comment: @Draco18s OK, thank you for correction.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich No worries, I just see the occasional comment that a question should be on Game Dev and most of the time either a) it's just fine for SO and doesn't need to be migrated at all, or b) it's a poor question for *both* sites. I'm just trying to be informative; it's perfectly fine to recommend that maybe a question would do better on another site in the network, but always make sure that either you check that site's rules or tell the asker to check the site's rules before posting. That said, "discussion type questions" aren't really allowed anywhere on the network.